# Insert Null value with pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have this code

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=RON\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=TestDB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM TestDB.dbo.Person')
city = 'NULL'
cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.Person (Name, Age, City) VALUES ('Bob',55,'{}')".format(city))
conn.commit()
```

That insert NULL **value** not realy NULL , I must put `'{}'` because if I want to set value in `city` variable it must be between `'`

```
city = 'NEW YORK'
cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.Person (Name, Age, City) VALUES ('Bob',55,'{}')".format(city))
```

So how can I handle that ? put NULL or value when the var is not NULL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameters to the query, not string formatting

```
city = None
cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.Person (Name, Age, City) VALUES ('Bob',55,?)", (city, ))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: And how can I get the full query that run with the args? for log ...

Answer (score 3):

You use parameters.

```py
Name, Age, City = 'Bob', 55, None
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TestDB.dbo.Person (Name, Age, City) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (Name, Age, City))
```

Comment: And how can I get the full query that run with the args? for log ...

Comment: You use the [transaction logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).